# Setting javaOptions in sbt:console task

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

How can I set `javaOptions` in an sbt project so that they'll be properly propagated inside the sbt:console task? I want have the vector incubator module visible inside the sbt console repl.

By adding the following to `build.sbt`:

```
ThisBuild / run / javaOptions += "--add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector"
```

I am able to *run* code using the vector module. Unfortunately, neither setting `ThisBuild / console / javaOptions := ...`, setting up `.jvmopts`, nor passing `--add-modules...` via _JAVA_OPTIONS doesn't seem to make the vector module visible from inside the sbt console:

```
sbt console                                                          
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx12g -Xms512M --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx12g -Xms512M --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
[info] welcome to sbt 1.7.3 (Oracle Corporation Java 17.0.2)
[info] loading project definition from /home/bartosz/work/programming/scala/sector/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to sector (in build file:/home/bartosz/work/programming/scala/sector/)
Welcome to Scala 3.2.1 (17.0.2, Java Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
                                                                                                                       
scala> import jdk.incubator.vector.IntVector
-- [E008] Not Found Error: -----------------------------------------------------
1 |import jdk.incubator.vector.IntVector
  |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |       value incubator is not a member of jdk
1 error found
```

The same import is visible from inside the `scala` interpreter.

```
$ scala
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx12g -Xms512M --add-modules=jdk.incubator.vector
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 17.0.2).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>   import jdk.incubator.vector.IntVector
import jdk.incubator.vector.IntVector
```

Comment: I think you're picking up `scala.jdk` instead of `jdk.`, and the result is different in Scala 2.11 because `scala.jdk` didn't exist until 2.13. Try `_root_.jdk`. (And if this turns out to be the answer, you or anyone should feel free to write it up as a proper SO answer.)

Comment: see also https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/15904

Comment: Oh, that was confusing! Yes importing `_root._jdk.incubator.vector` works in sbt console so it was a precedence not a visibility issue. Thank you for the answer @SethTisue